# Drop empty columns from specific set of filtered columns from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with multiple empty columns. I have few Flag columns among them. I need to drop only the empty Flag columns from my dataframe. I need a solution to filter out the Flag columns and drop them from the original dataframe.

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Last_Name': ['Smith', 'Tom', 'Brown'],
                     'First_Name': ['', '', ''],
                     'Age': [35, 45, 25],
                     'Flag1':['','',''],
                     'Flag2':['1','2','3'],
                     'Flag3':['','','']})
```

My **output** must be:

```
           Last_Name    First_Name  Age Flag2
       0   Smith                    35  1
       1   Tom                      45  2
       2   Brown                    25  3 ​
```

Comment: Do you want to drop only the flag columns or also the `First_Name` ?

Comment: Only the empty Flag columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `filter` with `replace` and `isnull` and then drop the columns:

```
drop_cols = df.filter(like='Flag').columns[df.filter(like='Flag').replace('',np.nan).isnull().all()]
df = df.drop(drop_cols, axis=1)

print(df)
  Last_Name First_Name  Age Flag2
0     Smith              35     1
1       Tom              45     2
2     Brown              25     3
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems somewhat simpler. Create a boolean condition on the columns, then index accordingly.

```
df = df.loc[:, df.astype(bool).all() | ~df.columns.str.match('Flag')]
df

  Last_Name First_Name  Age Flag2
0     Smith              35     1
1       Tom              45     2
2     Brown              25     3
```

Where,

```
df.astype(bool).all()

Last_Name      True
First_Name    False
Age            True
Flag1         False
Flag2          True
Flag3         False
dtype: bool
```

Tests the truthiness of the contents in the columns. Empty strings are falsy in nature, we take advantage of this.

Comment: this is, very creative. :)